# The Findbugs configuration file is not valid Error While uploading rule file to sonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

I have an issue when creating a new profile in sonarqube-4.1.2. Here is at I did:

1. I have sonar 3.1 rt now, that has 461 rules. Did a back up and saved the rule files containing rules for checkstyle. pmd and findbug.
2. I did try to create a new profile by clicking on "Create" in 4.1.2. It give me error 
   `The Findbugs configuration file is not valid : profile : profile   [hide]`
3. I also tried to Restore Profile which also is not importing the right number of rules. restoring only 345 rules.

In the log I see this error:

```
ERROR [o.s.p.f.FindbugsProfileImporter]  The Findbugs configuration file is not valid
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: profile : profile
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:68) ~[xstream-1.3.1.jar:na]
```

Please suggest what can be done to fix this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found this unanswered question when searching on the same issue. Do not use Create, use Restore Profile link above it for profile backups.